# Insert space between numbers after matching specific pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I have the following temperature data that needs to be manipulated. Thought about using `sed` to insert a space in between the data but, the data is changing constantly.

```
76 75 75 77 80 84 87 91 94 97100101101102101 97 92 89 86 84 82 81 79 78 77
```

I need it to look like this:

```
76 75 75 77 80 84 87 91 94 97 100 101 101 102 101 97 92 89 86 84 82 81 79 78 77
```

Right now, I am using the following code to parse out the highest value (where the numbers are clustered together):

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]' .../temp.txt | sort -rn | head -n 1
```

Comment: how can you tell where a number starts or ends...

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to do would be to modify whatever it is that generates the data so that it outputs it with a wider field width.

If that's not possible, then the following will de-mangle the output:

```
$ sed 's/\([ 1-9][0-9][0-9]\)/ \1/g' data | tr -s ' '
76 75 75 77 80 84 87 91 94 97 100 101 101 102 101 97 92 89 86 84 82 81 79 78 77
```

I put the `tr` at the end just to remove consecutive whitespaces in the output from `sed` (generated for all two-digit integers, except for the first one which, in this case, isn't matched by the regular expression).

But really, the generator of the data will need to be updated.

Comment: this is a clever usage of `tr -s ' '`!